# Slurm AccountingStorageEnforce=associations without effect

Tags: hpc

I'm managing a cluster with slurm and slurmdbd (with MySQL)

I have set the following option in /etc/slurm/slurm.conf

```
AccountingStorageEnforce=associations
```

I have reloaded the config:

```
scontrol reconfig
```

I have configured some associations in sacctmgr.

The problem is that I'm still able to submit a job with a non existing slurm user. What I have understood of the option AccountingStorageEnforce=associations is that a non existing user won't have the right to submit a job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that for this kind of modification to be taken into account, you need to do a full restart of slurm daemon, a reload is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The `slurm.conf` man page states that

```
   AccountingStorageEnforce
          This controls what level of association-based enforcement to impose on job submissions.  Valid options are any combination of associations,  limits,  nojobs,  nosteps,
          qos, safe, and wckeys, or all for all things.
          [...]
          When AccountingStorageEnforce is changed, a restart of the slurmctld daemon is required (not just a "scontrol reconfig").
```

so you have to make sure to restart the slurm controller daemon (and the secondary controller if configured.)